# Strange case insensitive select behavior Django + mysql

Tags: mysql, django

I Have simple model in Django:

```
class Tag(Model):
    name = CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
```

When I do:

```
t = 'Ansible'
print("Want tag: " + t)
tg, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=t)
print("Got tag: " + tg.name)
print("Query: {}".format(Tag.objects.filter(name=t).query))
print("Query result: {}".format(Tag.objects.filter(name=t).first().name))
```

I get result:

```
Want tag: Ansible
Got tag: ansible
Query: SELECT `main_tag`.`id`, `main_tag`.`slug`, `main_tag`.`name`, `main_tag`.`added_time`, `main_tag`.`public_tips_count`, `main_tag`.`private_tips_count` FROM `main_tag` WHERE `main_tag`.`name` = Ansible
Query result: ansible
```

I use `Django==1.10.3` and

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (armv7l) using readline 6.2
```

## What I expect?

I expect from `get_or_create` that it will create new tag named `Ansible`, but it returns some existent tag named `ansible`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql out of the box is case [insensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html). This behaviour has nothing to do with django.

> The default character set and collation are latin1 and
>   latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case
>   insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name
>   LIKE 'a%', you get all column values that start with A or a. To make
>   this search case sensitive, make sure that one of the operands has a
>   case sensitive or binary collation. For example, if you are comparing
>   a column and a string that both have the latin1 character set, you can
>   use the COLLATE operator to cause either operand to have the
>   latin1_general_cs or latin1_bin collation:

You can [make it case sensitive](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html) at system, database, table or even column levels.